# Docker on LXC - rm file: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): operation not permitted

Tags: docker, lxc

I have a rather simple Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-stretch

COPY files.zip /tmp
RUN \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip && \
    apt-get -y autoremove && \
    apt-get clean && \
    mkdir -p /app/data && \
    unzip /tmp/files.zip -d /app/data && \
    rm -f /tmp/files.zip
```

All works fine locally (Ubuntu 18.04, Docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056). But on LXC (sorry, don't know the version of LXC, Docker version 18.09.4, build d14af54 using storage driver overlay2) I get

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): 
operation not permitted
```

when I do `docker pull myimage:latest`. The culprit is line `rm -f /tmp/files.zip` (without it I am able to pull the image even on LXC).

I've tried to set all sorts of permissions, even `chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+rwx /tmp/files.zip` but on LXC it's just not possible to pull the image without that zip file.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Which storage driver is the docker install where it fails using?

Comment: ...and why is the zip file being there a problem? You don't pay storage costs more than once so long as your storage is copy-on-write / otherwise delta-backed.

Comment: Storage Driver: overlay2

Comment: overlay2 as well.

Comment: ...so, deletions are done in overlay2 by creation of a "whiteout file", which is a character device with magic numbers 0:0. If the backing filesystem is set up to not allow device creation, then you wouldn't be able to do deletions. Anyhow, if I personally needed to investigate this, I'd be grabbing a copy of sysdig and tracing the individual failed operations. (I'd also be paying attention to the permissions of the `/tmp` directory, not the `/tmp/files.zip` file itself; you can delete a file you don't have permission to write to, if-and-only-if you have write access to the directory it's in).